# While tuning guitar, 1st string coming as 2nd string on tuner ? What do I do?

Tags: guitar, tuning, tuner

While tuning guitar, 1st string coming as 2nd string on tuner ? What do I do ?
Happening for the first time.

Comment: This question about tuning the high e string is very similar and may have additional answers that may be helpful (http://music.stackexchange.com/q/41062/16897)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the strings are properly in place, my guess is that the string is either too tight or too loose. So, instead of the usual E that it's supposed to be, you see a B. Just tune it until it gets to E. Just make sure to understand if you have to loosen it or tighten it.

It might help you to find someone who knows how to properly tune a guitar so as to show you.

There are many youtube videos that show how to tune a guitar for beginners:

Moreover, sometimes the tuner listens to the fifth, because it's the first overtone over the octave. So, try playing the 12th fret harmonic to see what the tuner listens. Another solution could be to tune the other 5 strings and then play the B string on the 5th fret and see if the sound is the same as the the open high E string.

Comment: 5th fret B showing high E, that's normal. 12 fret for the 1st and 2nd string is not showing up any result

Comment: @user3656142 that's what it's supposed to show. Now try to tune the high E. Play the 5th fret on the B string and then the open high E string and see if the E string is higher or lower than the other one. Then you'll be able to see if you have to loosen or tighten it

Comment: If it is an electric guitar plugged direct to the tuner, you might get more tuner sensitivity by turning up the pickup volume and possibly try a different pickup. I know that tuners seem to prefer my bridge humbucker over my neck single coil.